# Deserialize a Dynamic JSON Array on C# WebForm

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, datatable, deserialization

Hi I am generating a JSON on my API that I am trying to use on codebehind C# in my web application but I cannot deserialize well.

My JSON has an object with JSON arrays and the element inside the array are dynamic so I cannot create a fixed class with those items becuase my JSON can have N ITEMS.

```
{
    "MAINOBJET": [{
        "ITEM1": "23800",
        "ITEM2": "Dahl; Police",
        "ITEM3": "test@test.net"
    },
    {
        "ITEM1": "23802",
        "ITEM2": "Steve ; Police",
        "ITEM3": "test2@test.net"
    }]
}
```

So how can I deserialize it to a DataTable, list or a Dictionary?
Thank you

Comment: Have you done a google Search..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you can do some thing like the following this example should be able to get you started .. replace the structure / example with your Jason Text

lets say that my JSON Script looks like the following

```
{
    "some_number": 253.541, 
    "date_time": "2012-26-12T11:53:09Z", 
    "serial_number": "SN8675309"
    "more_data": {
        "field1": 1.0
        "field2": "hello JSON Deserializer" 
    }
}
```

assign you JSON jsonText to a variable and pass it to the following C# Code

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var jsonSerialization = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictObj = jsonSerialization.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(jsonText);
Console.WriteLine(dictObj["some_number"]); //outputs 253.541
Console.WriteLine(dictObj["more_data"]["field2"]); //outputs hello JSON Deserializer
```

Comment: That's awesome news ..I am happy that I was able to lend you a helping hand